# Does upstart have a built in way to respawn a process that is not stopped using initctl stop in specific intervals?

Tags: process, service, upstart

We thought the following directives would try to respawn the process 10 times in 60 seconds (i.e. once every 6 seconds):

```
respawn
respawn limit 10 60
```

However these directives restart the process as soon as it is crashed. So it might actually respawn the process 10 times in 1 second.

Is there a way to configure our service so that when it crashes, it tries ti respawn it 10 times, once every 6 seconds?

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu Upstart Cookbook has [an answer](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#delay-respawn-of-a-job) for this:

> If a job specifies respawn, but you want to delay the respawn for some
>   reason, simply use a post-stop stanza:
>
> ```
> respawn
> exec mydaemon
> post-stop exec sleep 10
> ```
>
> Now, every time mydaemon exits with a non-zero return code, the job
>   will sleep for 10 seconds before Upstart restarts it.
>
> For a real service, you would probably use a post-stop script stanza
>   to perform a check rather than simply sleeping.

To be honest, I'm not sure if and why *post-stop* is called only on non-zero job exit codes, but this is the solution the manual suggests. You can always use `post-start script` and add a check to make `sleep ...` conditional.